# GPIO I2C IMU on OrangePi CM4 Running Android Doesn't Interface With Native Apps

Tags: android, gpio, i2c, imu, orange-pi

I need an [Adafruit LSM6DSOX + LIS3MDL](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4517) to act as the IMU sensor array by default for apps running on Android, which is installed on an OrangePi CM4. I know I have the IMU connected properly, as I can get input through the OrangePi wiring app (which comes preinstalled on the android image). I don't know where to start in terms of realizing this, and I can't find anything of use on the internet (and ChatGPT let me down too). I had originally hoped Android would recognize the i2c device and use it automatically, but it didn't and there aren't any settings or documentation for doing such. Does anyone have any pointers or tidbits of information that could help me with this?

Comment: Check with the Android ROM creators for notes or info on supported IMU modules. Search specifically with the version of Android ROM you are using.